# Append one table to another

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

Is there currently a way to append data from one table to another via. the API and PHP?

For instance:

I have two tables;

- today
- all_time

at the end of every day I want to append today into all_time and both tables use the same schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, you just need to pass in the async query configuration `writeDisposition=WRITE_APPEND` and setup the destination tables.

read about writeDisposition here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource

Other than this, you can directly write the results of the query to a table in query mode, using the Destination Table option that is available under Show Options.

[image]

Comment: I noticed the way to do it through the web UI, and that resource does help in terms of the documentation - I guess now I just need to figure out how to set everything properly with the php-client.